# how to upload different keystore apk file to google play developer

Tags: google-play

I have new apk of my app with different keystore (the old one is lost). When I upload it tell me must use the old keystore which I don't have now. How to upload new apk file with new keystore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant upload different versions with different keystores.
You need to upload it as a new app.